Unable to publish an App Bundle because of the Google Play 64-bit requirement
I'm encountering a persistent 64-bit error when trying to publish an update for my Android application's App Bundle on Google Play.

Technical Setup:

Project Type: Standard Kotlin project for Android
Android build tools version: 34.0.0
minSdkVersion: 24
compileSdkVersion: 34
targetSdkVersion: 33
Android Gradle Plugin version: 8.4.1
Android Gradle Wrapper version: gradle-8.6-bin.zip

Context:

I've meticulously followed Google's official documentation for App Bundle publishing, specifically regarding 64-bit library requirements.
I create the App Bundle with the following Gradle task bundleRelease.
My project successfully runs within a 64-bit simulator inside my IDE.
I've verified that the three native libraries within the App Bundle's "lib" folder have indeed their 64-bit (arm64-v8a and x86_64 architectures) version using the file command.
I confirm I do not utilize Unity or any Native Development Kit (NDK).
There is no RenderScript usage.
I have tried without success ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'.
I have read other SO posts like this without any success.

I've interacted with Google Play support, but they were unable to resolve the issue and closed the ticket, stating they couldn't provide a more specific answer. Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I don't know what checks Google does to identify that your app contains 32bit code. One simple measure would be to use the aab bundle you uploaded to Google and extract it to a new folder. Then execute the Linux command file on every extracted file. Filter out all files that are identified as ELF files and check if they are 32 bin (arm-v7) or 64 bin (arm-v8a).

Yep, done that already as mentioned in the three native libraries point using the file cmd. Everything is okay though. Thanks for the tip anyway.

My recommendation was targeting on all files included in the aab, not only those you know they are 64bit .so files.

What does your native library directories look like? (I.e. what are files are under lib/ recursively?)

@Pierre I have three native files per these folders: armeabi-v7a, x86, arm64-v8a and x86_64. As mentioned, I've ensured each file corresponds to its architecture. I have updated the case with a new answer which doesn't make any sense to me.

Hi @Pierre, do you guys have any idea why could be the reason behind this behaviour? We went crazy until we find out that unique different between working/non working versions, but we don't see any sense. However, the algorithm of Google Play rejects it.

Yeah doesn't make much sense, and it's hard to believe that's the only difference... Are you able to share the AAB with me by any chance?

I know, I thought the same and I personally checked and tested everything myself. Our CI/CD is fully determinist: it's fully isolated, reproducible and there is no variability. Of course I can provide you those two AAB with that unique diff code between them. How could I reach you?

Share a Drive link and grant me access when I request? Or however else you wish.

Found the reason... this was not a trivial investigation, but a fun one nonetheless!

Android automatically considers any APK as only working in a 32-bit environment if it contains a file with the extension ".bc" (RenderScript) -- This is documented here: https://developer.android.com/games/optimize/64-bit#renderscript-and-64-bit
You seem to be using an obfuscator which changes the name of some files. One of the files under directory META-INF/ does not have an extension but the name of the file was renamed to com.package.name.Bc <-- Android (and thus Play) thought this was a RenderScript file because of the seemingly extension ".bc" and thus flagged the AAB as being 32-bit regardless of the native libraries available.
A re-run of the obfuscator after having commented one line of code led to a different random file name com.package.name.Cc and that's why the other AAB worked.
Granted, it would help debugging if the error message included the reason why it's not 64-bit compliant... :/

Jesus Christ...I reviewed the guidelines over and over again, and exchange many emails with Google's support without any luck, and finally that was it hehe. That one was tough, but although misleading, it makes sense now. That diff didn't have any sense at all. Perhaps adding a lowercase check and a vague RenderScript bitcode signature check would help to discard most of these issues. Thanks a lot for your help Pierre.

Yeah, unfortunately, that ship has sailed long ago when someone submitted code in the Android codebase only checking for the .bc suffix and the release went live. There's no going back after that since there will always be devices with that code running... I'll see if the error message can be improved in the Play Console.

Oh yes, I was referring to add those checks in Play Console so that there wouldn't even be any error messages for the majority of these cases minimising those false positives. No error would be raised to me for example because the capital ".B" or the bitcode signature stands to RS.

Believe it or not, after a long divide and conquer exercise comparing the ongoing version to a former 64 bit compliant one, this is what I've found out:

NOTE: Code has been simplified at max

App Bundle A - Google Play 64 bit compliant
    // Invoked from MainApplication
    val deviceInfo = AndroidUtils.addDeviceInformationHeader()
    println(deviceInfo)
}

object AndroidUtils {
    @JvmStatic
    fun addDeviceInformationHeader(): String {
        return StringBuilder().toString()
    }
}

App Bundle B - NON Google Play 64 bit compliant
    // Invoked from MainApplication
    // val deviceInfo = AndroidUtils.addDeviceInformationHeader()
    // println(deviceInfo)
}

object AndroidUtils {
    @JvmStatic
    fun addDeviceInformationHeader(): String {
        return StringBuilder().toString()
    }
}

Nothing else changes in the project from App Bundle A to B. Nothing at all. Both App Bundle A and B were generated from the exact same Docker-based environment. Each build starts from a blank checkout with only the code difference you see in A and B. The build itself executes the bundleRelease Gradle task.
While the cause remains unclear, I'm happy to share more information with Google in case they help improve the clarity or accuracy of their 64-bit compliance checks.
